# bundle exec rake db:migrate worked, but development.sqlite3 is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm new to RoR. The following line executed normally:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Output showed that it is migrated. `development.sqlite3` and `production.sqlite3` were created but empty, although schema.rb was written properly. The users table was successfully created, but without any records. Also I executed:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

`test.sqlite3` is created and also written properly. This is the content of the file inside the migration file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :users do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.string :email

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

Kindly help me solve the problem. Let me know if any other details need to be specified.

Comment: it might help to add the code/command you used to test db is empty?

Comment: i think what you are looking for is to fill your database with seed content `bundle exec rake db:seed`

Comment: @sa77 Thank you very much! That solved it! Also, I'm curious to know what the problem had been and what does `bundle exec rake db:seed` mean?

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:seed` fills up your database with initial data (seed data) for your database. you can define your seed data in `db/seeds.rb`

Answer (score 1):

So `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` probably sets your environment to test.

That would be the reason why you'll end up with a working test database.

If you want to have the data in the development database, you need to set the environment to development.

Try `RACK_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`.

Although the cleaner solution is to create a seed file. See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data